# How to have 2 sequently two retrofit requests and receive as a result Flowable<List<InfoDetail>>?

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I have two retrofit requests

```
 @GET("user/info")
Single<Infos> infoLists();

@GET("user/info/{id}")
Single<InfoDetail> shoppingListItem(@Path("id") int id);
```

Receiving the list of UserInfos I want to fetch more detail info for each user

```
public Flowable<List<Single<UserExtended>>> test() {
      return fetchInfoItems().
            map(Items::items).
            toObservable().
            flatMapIterable(items -> items)
            .map(itemDetail ->    fetchUserDetail(itemDetail.getId())
                    .map(userInfoDetail -> new UserDetail(userInfoDetail.id,.....))

            .toList()
            .toFlowable();}
```

I want to receive as return `Flowable<List<UserExtended>>` while I receive `Flowable<List<Single<UserExtended>>>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try flatMapSingle() and your gradle version should be 3.0.0-beta4

```
public Flowable<List<UserExtended>> test() {
  return fetchInfoItems().
        map(Items::items).
        toObservable().
        flatMapIterable(items -> items)
       .flatMapSingle(itemDetail ->    fetchUserDetail(itemDetail.getId())
         .map(userInfoDetail -> new UserDetail(userInfoDetail.id,.....))

        .toList()
        .toFlowable();}
```